# Sign out google user from android app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication

I have been able to authenticate users from android app to my app engine site using this blog post;
http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app

For the first login; permission dialog appears. And after allowing the app the user is authenticated. How can i sign out this user? How can i remove the granted permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It is only removed after you uninstall the app. So if this is for testing, re-installing will do. Otherwise you just have to live with it.

Comment: after uninstalling i still don't see the grant permission screen @Nikolay.

Comment: This is strange, there should be a package removed boradcast receiver that does this. What version/device is this on?.

Comment: it is android 2.3 on huawei ideos x5. And the sample app is available here; https://github.com/Arachnid/AEAuth There must be a setting in the google account settings page to revoke this permissions. But i cannot find it. The thing i want to do is to sign out one user and sign in with another one on the same device. Without uninstalling ofcourse.

Comment: There is no such setting. If you have root access you can check the grants database directly and maybe delete the relevant row.

Comment: i mean a setting in the google account settings web page not in the device. There is this page but i cannot see my app here;
https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=tr

Comment: This is a ClientLogin token, so it won't show up in AuthSub. There is no way to revoke it. You can only revoke the local Android grand (basically a list of UIDs that can get tokens).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to revoke permission for one app, you must enter your account setting on web, then security->access manage. This's my favorite way.
some link likes: https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security